# Feature Extraction from Accelerometers for classification

Tags: fft, classification, machine-learning

I am looking into algorithms/techniques for feature extraction for accelerometer data - to then be used in classification.

FFT is incredibly popular, however would this work on accelerometer data?  I've also seen PCA, but that isn't quite so popular.

Will PCA work as a possible feature extraction algorithm?

Comment: What is the use case for this? Gesture detection?

Comment: To classify different movements based on the accelerometer data.